# Cannot pass AutoSeededRandomPool as parameter when using CryptoPP::RSA, error C2729

Tags: c++, parameters, crypto++, declspec

I am working with implement RSA using Crypto++. I am trying to generate a pair of RSA keys (public and private) to file like this.

The code can run perfect when I put all in `main`. When I try to split it to a function and pass `AutoSeededRandomPool` object as parameter like this:

```cxx
int generateKeyToFile(
    AutoSeededRandomPool rnd, 
    string publicKeyFileName, string privateKeyFileName){
    try
    {
        RSA::PrivateKey rsaPrivate;
        rsaPrivate.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rnd, 3072);

        RSA::PublicKey rsaPublic(rsaPrivate);
        EncodePrivateKey(privateKeyFileName, rsaPrivate);
        EncodePublicKey(publicKeyFileName, rsaPublic);

        cout << "Successfully generated and saved RSA keys" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    catch (CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When build project, I got the error:

> error C2719: 'rnd': formal parameter with __declspec(align('8')) won't
>   be aligned

I cannot found a exact Crypto++ related result for this error from Google, but I found some result for [error code C2719](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/373ak2y1.aspx). Its content:

> 'parameter': formal parameter with __declspec(align('#')) won't be
>   aligned
>
> The align __declspec modifier is not permitted on function parameters.
>   Function parameter alignment is controlled by the calling convention
>   used. For more information, see Calling Conventions.
>
> The following sample generates C2719 and shows how to fix it:
>
> ```
> // C2719.cpp  
> void func(int __declspec(align(32)) i);   // C2719  
> // try the following line instead  
>  void func(int i);
> ```

I didn't get any idea from this apply this "solution" to my case yet.

Seem like `AutoSeededRandomPool` cannot be passed as parameter. Is there someway to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cxx
int generateKeyToFile(
     AutoSeededRandomPool rnd, 
    string publicKeyFileName, string privateKeyFileName){
    ...
}
```

Use a reference:

```cxx
int GenerateKeyToFile(
    RandomNumberGenerator& rnd, 
    const string& publicKeyFileName,
    const string& privateKeyFileName)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I'm not sure `AutoSeededRandomPool` is copy constructable. I think things are working as expected because you probably should not copy one. Just pass it by reference or by pointer.